# How to work item get history items for changes where only links changed

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I work with the Azure DevOps API and use the [Revisions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/revisions/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) function to get the work item history.

I have seen a strange behavior when the work item (test case in my example) changed *only by removing a work item link* (no comment added nor other fields updated). This change is properly displayed in the "History" tab of the work item in the web interface, but the Revisions API does not return it. In fact it looks like that the revision number of the work item was not even increased.

Is there a way to get also these history items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to get also these history items?

You can try [Updates-List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/updates/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) or [Updates-Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/updates/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1).

**Updates-List:**

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workItems/{id}/updates?api-version=5.1
```

**Updates-Get:**

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workItems/{id}/updates/{updateNumber}?api-version=5.1
```

**More Details:**

Here's my history of Test Case work item:

[image]

The Updates-List will return count 4:

[image]

While the Revisions-List will return count 2(It **ignores** the changes where I add/delete the link only):

[image]

From the response of Updates-list you can find the history about link added/deleted:

[image]

Comment: how can I get latest revision of a workitem? I tried with odata query to order by rev and take top 1 but the result is always top 1 with out applying filter.
My Query:
myrepo/_apis/wit/workItems/30/updates?$orderby=Rev desc&$top=1&api-version=6.0