# Devops work item get top one revision data order by descending

Tags: azure-devops, odata, power-automate

I am trying to get azure devops work its history/revisions using Updates-List or [Updates-Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/revisions/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP).

How can I get latest revision of a work item? I tried with odata query to order by rev and take top 1 but the result is always top 1 with out applying filter.

My Query: myrepo/_apis/wit/workItems/30/updates?$orderby=rev desc&$top=1&api-version=6.0

Similar stackoverflow reference is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62452189/how-to-work-item-get-history-items-for-changes-where-only-links-changed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like $orderby is not supported in these type of REST API calls. As a workaround you could use the [reverse](https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#reverse) and [first](https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#first) functions after you retrieved the list of updates/revisions.

Below is an example for a single work item.

In a compose use the following expression to retrieve the last updates record.

```
first(reverse(body('Send_an_HTTP_request_to_Azure_DevOps')['value']))
```

[image]