# How can I track if the iteration path has been changed in Azure Devops?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, iteration, change-management

I need to find a way to create queries (if possible) to track if the iteration path has been changed on a feature level.
Is it possible?
I have to track hundreds of feature so I cannot "follow" them.

I cannot seem to find a solution

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use REST API to fetch the work items of type "Feature", ask for field System.History, then on your end search for phrase "changed Iteration Path to". [Here is the reference to start.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/updates/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1&tabs=HTTP#list-of-work-item-updates) You can also refer to [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62452189/how-to-work-item-get-history-items-for-changes-where-only-links-changed) answer. It looks like you'll need to query one work item history at once. So you'll need some kind of cache / database to store last fetched state. You'll need last date time when you checked the items, then fetch via API items with Changed Date after your last check. It sounds like time triggered function.